# Display weight attribute on Woocommerce product archives

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have tried this code to display the weight attribute below product archives on Woocommerce. But it appears below the "add to cart" button. I would like the weight attribute to appear *before* the "add to cart" button.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'rs_show_weights', 9 );

function rs_show_weights() {

    global $product;
    $weight = $product->get_weight();

    if ( $product->has_weight() ) {
        echo '<div class="product-meta"><span class="product-meta-label">Weight: </span>' . $weight . get_option('woocommerce_weight_unit') . '</div></br>';
    }
}
```

What would be the correct code to achieve this?

Comment: Use `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` instead of `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`

Comment: I replace woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item with woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button and the weight attribute disappears. Can you share a working code for this? Cheers

Comment: @MosheGross `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` hook is for single product page, not for loop products.

Comment: @isholacode You can try changing the priority to `6` or `7` instead of `9`, **Note: if your theme makes changes in default hooks priority or attach functions with different hooks then you need to check the theme code and find out which hook you should use with your theme customizations**